# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 implementation without Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

Is there a custom implementation for ASP.NET Identity 2.0 that does not use Entity Framework? I'm hoping for something that does not use a full blown ORM but something along the lines of Dapper. The reason I'm asking is because I am not using Entity Framework anywhere else in the project so I would like to stay away from it if possible.

I know I could work on my own implementation but I do not have the extra time to spend on that.

Comment: At least a comment before down voting?

Comment: Speak to this guy http://stackoverflow.com/q/25632581/809357

Comment: I started this project. It's early and has a long way to go but hopefully someone else will find it useful. https://github.com/ryanrodemoyer/AltProvidersForAspNetIdentity2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Frustration and lack of other options forced me to do it myself. Here is the project page on GitHub: https://github.com/ryanrodemoyer/AltProvidersForAspNetIdentity2. It's a ways off from a tested usable project but it's a starting point.

Comment: This seems to be a common problem. Each new version of Identity obliges folk to surgically remove EF. Did this solution find it's way into production code?

Comment: Bleh, looks promising, but I can't get it working after a couple of hours.  The async methods are MIA and /Identity/UserStore.cs looks like an EF class.  Dapper.Rainbow probably received a breaking update as the async methods are still in there or Visual Studio is referencing classes differently, I noticed that Table<T, blah> might be pointing back to ADO instead of the Dapper implementation.  Oh well, I found another example, will update this if that works.

Comment: @Ryan-rodemoyer is there any video also on the same as I'm a beginner in asp.net identity membership model?

Comment: Also there is little bit abstract level help given on the microsoft docs page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity